# How do I write script to start multiple services in centos?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, centos

I am having multi-node cluster of Hadoop, Kafka, Zookeeper, Spark.

I am running following commands to start respective service,

```
$ ./Hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
$ ./zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
$ ./Kafka/Kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server-properties.sh
$ ./spark/sbin/start-all.sh
```

and so on..

can anyone tell me how to write a script to automate this process of running each command individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a simple shell script with all these commands and running that script instead? For example, following is a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
./Hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
./zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
./kafka/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server-properties.sh
./spark/sbin/start-all.sh
```

and so on ...

Comment: Thank you @F Baig